# Completely removing loaded forms with jQuery -

Tags: javascript, jquery

So I'm using .load() to load a view into an element - and when I'm done with it I do an .innerHTML = '' to get rid of it.

But if I do it more than once (i.e. close and open the element) - the form is definitely gone in between and reloaded, but when I submit it submits duplicates.

Here is the code:

```
 $('a.comments').click(function(e){
            e.preventDefault();
            // $('.overlaybackground').addClass('open');
            Component.Overlay.toggleOverlay();
            $('#commentcontainer').load($(this).attr('href'), function(){
                Component.Forms.init(page, {});
            });
        });

        $('.overlaybackground').click(function(e){
            if(e.target.className == 'overlaybackground open'){
                 e.preventDefault();
                Component.Overlay.toggleOverlay();
            // $('.overlaybackground').remove('*:not(#commentcontainer)');
            document.getElementById('commentcontainer').innerHTML = '';
        }
        });
```

Comment: What is `Component.Forms.init`?

Comment: @dfsq a HUGE oversight by me. the $(document).on('submit') I had for the forms was being called IN the init I was calling on open. Which caused it to attach the event listener over and over again. Thank you! I can't believe the issue was that simple.

Answer (score 0):

Try the following:

```
$('#commentcontainer').empty()
```

Comment: The issue ended up being my calling Component.Forms every time it opened. Shouldn't have done that. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Not sure of the specific scenario. But if you only want to toggle the visual, simply toggle the **CSS** property **display** of the form instead of removing it from the DOM:

display:none<--> display:block

Comment: Thanks - but the specific element had to be repopulated iwth different views every time. Thanks.